# if row[0] in row[1] print row

Tags: python, list, csv, for-loop

I have a csv file that has 2 columns. I am simply trying to figure if each `row[0]` value is in some `row[1]` and if so, to print `row`.

Items in csv file:

```
COL1,   COL2
1-A,    1-A
1-B,    2-A
2-A,    1-B
2565,   2565
51Bc,   51Bc
5161,   56
811,    65
681,    11
55,     3
3,      55
```

Code:

```
import csv
doc= csv.reader(open('file.csv','rb'))

for row in doc:
    if row[0] in row[1]:
        print row[0]
```

The end result should be:

```
1-A
1-B
2-A
2565
51Bc
55
3
```

Instead, it is giving me:

```
1-A
2565
51Bc
```

It prints those numbers because they are right next to each other side by side but what I need it to do is get the first item in COL1 and see if it finds it in the entire COL2 list and print if it does. Not see if its beside each other and print it.

Comment: You need to loop through the `csv` once to make a list out of all of the `row[1]` elements. Then you will actually have a list that you can do an `in` comparison on. The current way, you're only comparing one element to one other element.

Comment: How would I make it loop through the whole thing once before giving it an argument?

Comment: Your title says "if row[0] in row[1]". Your description says "I am simply trying to figure if row[1] is in row[0]." You realize those are not the same thing, right?

Comment: Yes that was my fault. Sorry I didn't know exactly what how to call it when i specified row since it calls the same thing regardless. Having them as a list is how I figured out that I said the same thing and didn't make sense of it. Just me being a noob at this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say `for row in doc`, it's only getting one pair of elements and putting them in `row`. So there's no possible way `row[1]` can hold that entire column, at any point in time. You need to do an initial loop to get that column as a list, then loop through the `csv` file again to do the comparison. Actually, you could store both columns in separate lists, and only have to open the file once.

```
import csv
doc= csv.reader(open('file.csv','rb'))

# Build the lists.
first_col = []
second_col = set()
for row in doc:
    first_col.append(row[0])
    second_col.add(row[1])

# Now actually do the comparison.
for item in first_col:
    if item in second_col:
        print item
```

As per abarnert's suggestion, we're using a `set()` for the second column. `set`s are optimized for looking up values inside it, which is all we're doing with it. A `list` is optimized for looping through every element, which is what we do with `first_col`, so that makes more sense there.

Comment: and I feel pretty dumb right about now... Your explanation was on point! I greatly appreciate your answer. Thanks a lot buddy!

Comment: Good explanation—but it's probably better to use a set for `second_col`—it's conceptually a little clearer, and faster to boot.

Comment: @abarnert good point, I changed my answer as per your suggestion.

Comment: Now I see why we should separate these from list and sets. I have much to learn but grateful to have you two explain this to me. Thanks a ton!